# creating a drop down list when pulling data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, drop-down-menu

hi i am wanting to display the categories that i am pulling from the database in a drop down list. currently they are being pulled and just displayed in a long line in a menu bar i have created. the code i have so far is:

```
    <?php
    /*
    Displaying List of Categories from the Table - Category and that is limited to 6
    */
    $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category ", $con);
    if(!$qry)
    {
    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
    }

    /* Fetching datas from the field "category" and article id is transfered to articles.php file */
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
    echo "&nbsp;<a href=articles.php?cat=".$row['category'].">".$row['category']."</a>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    ?>
```

any help would be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your while statement to:

```
echo '<select name="list">';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    echo '<option>'.$row['category'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: yes it turns it into a drop down list but before when there was no drop down list and i selected the different options the corresponding info was being pulled from database, now when i select the option from the drop down list the option being selected is not retrieving the data? @Aamir Siddique

Comment: you need to use field names (defined in db) in place of `category`.